# Gigya phone registration

Tags: ios, json, gigya

I'm using Gigya as a single-sign-on system for my iOS app.
It is integrated and I can log in with both Twitter, Facebook and manual email registration.

As both Facebook and Twitter do not return mobile phone numbers, I'm appending this information after successful registration/login along with some other information like e-mail. I am able to successfully update fields in the profile like username, nickname etc, but not phones.

A description of the profile structure can be found here:
http://developers.gigya.com/020_Client_API/020_Accounts/010_Objects/Profile

So I figure to post:
{@"phones": @[@{@"number" : _phoneNumberTextfield.text}]}

as the profile content. Which is apparently alright, since the response has statusReason OK.

All good, and if I add other fields, they get updated. But when I retrieve the profile, there is no phone number there. I tried to append the field "type" as per the definition, but then I get: 400025 Write access validation error.

So the update call tells me everything is OK, but it isn't appending the number to the profile. Adding the type to each number entry in the array of @"phones" gives an access violation.

I've been through Gigya's API spec and can't find any working examples or even JSON examples of this situation; does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: We had to make the call from serverside which should have sufficient rights whereas I was trying to make it clientside, but I'll also try the extraProfileFields just to see if clientside would've worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're retrieving the profile using accounts.getAccountInfo, make sure you include the "extraProfileFields = phones" parameter. The phones array will not be returned by default.

http://developers.gigya.com/037_API_reference/020_Accounts/accounts.getAccountInfo

Answer (score 1):

The Gigya SDK on the server-side represents data as JSON objects, which have the ability to represent nested objects under a key or arrays.

In the case of the "profile.phone" property on the account, this is stored as an array of objects, as detailed below:

```
{
    "profile": {
        "phones": [
            { "type": "phone", "number": "8005551234" },
            { "type": "cell", "number": "8885551234" }
        ]
    }
}
```

Typically, the when using Gigya's iOS API, it is common to maps these JSON concepts to the the NSMutableDictionary and NSMutableArray classes respectively and then to serialize the data using the NSJSONSerialization class.

So, for example, if we wanted to set the phone numbers on an account with Gigya like shown above, then you would need to accomplish this using something like the following code:

```
    NSMutableDictionary *phone1 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [phone1 setObject:@"phone" forKey:@"type"];
    [phone1 setObject:@"8005551234" forKey:@"number"];

    NSMutableDictionary *phone2 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [phone2 setObject:@"cell" forKey:@"type"];
    [phone2 setObject:@"8885551234" forKey:@"number"];

    NSMutableArray *phones = [NSMutableArray array];
    [phones addObject:phone1];
    [phones addObject:phone2];

    NSMutableDictionary *profile = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [profile setObject:phones forKey:@"phones"];

    NSError *error;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:profile
                                                       options:0
                                                         error:&error];

    GSRequest *request = [GSRequest requestForMethod:@"accounts.setAccountInfo"];
    [request.parameters setObject:jsonString forKey:@"profile"];
    [request sendWithResponseHandler:^(GSResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"Success");
            // Success! Use the response object.
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"error");
            // Check the error code according to the GSErrorCode enum, and handle it.
        }
    }];
```

Alternatively, you could construct a JSON string directly; but the above strategy tends to be much more flexible to any changes that need to be done when adding new properties.